# Proving that $12 \mid \sigma(12n - 1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to prove that for any positive integer $n$ the integer

$$N_n = 12 n - 1$$

the sum of the divisors is divisible by 12,

$$12 \mid \sigma(N_n)$$

Where the sum of the divisors is defined as

$$\sigma(n) = \sum_{d \vert n} d$$

I have verified the claim for several $n$ but fail to see any pattern. Sometimes $N_n$ is prime and sometimes not. The only thing I noticed is that every "pair" of divisors $d$ and $N / d$ sum to 12, but I am also not able to prove that rigorously.

Comment: Hint: For and $d\mid 12n-1,$ $d+\frac{12n-1}d$ is divisible by $12.$

Comment: Just now I noticed https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2385675/sum-of-2-factors-of-12n-1-always-a-new-multiple-of-12-or-prime-contains-a which is quite similar, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conjecture about pairs of divisors is correct.

Let $12 n - 1 = x y$, with $x, y$ positive integers, so $x, y$ is one of these pairs. Note that $x \ne y$, as $12 n - 1$ is not a square, as an odd square is congruent to $1$ modulo $4$.

Modulo $3$ we have $x y \equiv = -1 \pmod{3}$, so let us say $x \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$ and $y \equiv -1 \pmod{3}$.

Modulo $4$ we have $x y \equiv = -1 \pmod{4}$, so we have

- either $x \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ and $y \equiv -1 \pmod{4}$
- or $x \equiv -1 \pmod{4}$ and $y \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$

In both cases we have

- $x + y \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$ and
- $x + y \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$,

so that $x + y \equiv 0 \pmod{12}$.

Comment: Note for $12n-1=ab$ you can also exploit $(a+1)(b+1)=a+b+(ab+1)=a+b+12n$ and since $a,b$ odd, you get the divisibility by $4$ of $(a+1)(b+1)$.

Comment: Very clear, thank you. I guess that for the "modulo 3" case you also should consider both cases but conclude that that the sum of x and y will always be congruent to 0?

Comment: For the "modulo $3$" case, which I consider first, I am still free to name "$x$" the one divisor which is congruent to $1$ modulo $3$. That's what I mean by *let us say*...